# Substituting total derivative d for partial derivative \partial

Tags: derivatives, economics, partial-derivative

In economic models it seems to be commonplace to substitute a total derivative derived from one equation, say $\frac{d k}{d \tau}$, for the partial derivative derived from another equation, say $\frac{\partial k}{\partial \tau}$.

Why is it allowed to perform this substitution? After all, $d$ and $\partial$ are different concepts, are they not?

---

Here is a (simplified) example from a model on tax competition by [Köthenbürger (2002)](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1016511918510):

A firm maximizes profits from the production and sale of a single good. One of the resulting first-order conditions is $f_k(k) = r(\tau) + \tau$, where $f_k$ is the derivative of the production function with respect to the input capital $k$, $r$ is the interest rate, and $\tau$ is the tax rate of a tax on capital. Differentiating with respect to $k$ and $\tau$ on both sides, we can rearrange to arrive at

$$
\frac{d k}{d \tau} = \frac{\frac{\partial r}{\partial \tau} + 1}{f_{kk}}
$$

The model also contains the maximization problem of a government which yields the first-order condition

$$
\frac{d u}{d \tau} = u_c \left( - f_{kk} \frac{\partial k}{\partial \tau} k + \dots \right) + \dots \overset{!}{=} 0
$$

The analysis of the model continues with a substitution of $\frac{d k}{d \tau}$ from the first equation for $\frac{\partial k}{\partial \tau}$ in the second equation.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, the substitution actually makes sense, if you put on your economist's hat.

The first expression $\frac{dk}{d \tau}$ comes from differentiating firm's optimal condition, marginal product = marginal return of capital.

In the government's problem, $\frac{\partial k}{\partial \tau}$ is the rate of change of capital conditioned on all other variables controlled by the government being held constant. But presumably this is a general equilibrium model. Also, those other variables are exogenous to the firm. So *in equilibrium*, this $\frac{\partial k}{\partial \tau}$ must be the same as the firm's  $\frac{dk}{d \tau}$.

For the same reason, one assumes government's capital is the same as firm's capital, as is always done in decentralized equilibrium models.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into the model. Your explanation somehow resonates well with me, but I still don't understand the 'rule' that is at work here. Could you say a little more as to why the assumption of being in an equilibrium equalizes $\frac{\partial k}{\partial \tau}$ and $\frac{d k}{d \tau}$? How does the economic intuition behind these terms differ outside of an equilibrium?

Comment: Well, in economics, we only do analysis in equilibrium, meaning all markets clear and all agents optimize. Why do we assume government's $k$ is the same as the firm's $k$ is the same as the consumer's $k$ (if there are consumers in the model)? Because in equilibrium, the capital market clears. Likewise, in equilibrium, there is only one rate of change of $k$ with respect to $\tau$ that is experienced by all agents and this rate of change must be consistent with all agents' optimizing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why people do this is that, in a typical economic model, there are usually a lot of variables that are intercorrelated in one way or another. It is difficult to isolate just two variables where one is dependent on the other, and only on this single independent variable but not anything else. Therefore, most such comparative static relationship should be indeed partial derivatives. Whenever we substitute the total derivative for the partial, what we assume is that, at this moment, only the relationship between these two variables, *ceteris paribus,* is of our interest. Therefore the $d$ notation effectively indicates that we are holding everything else constant. In this regard, the total and the partial are the same indeed.

Comment: Would this be a correct interpretation of your answer: "When we took the total derivative of the firm's first-order condition we should have written $\partial \tau$ and $\partial k$ instead of $d \tau$ and $d k$, because we were holding all other variables constant. The notational problem wouldn't have appeared in the first place." If this is so, why was I trained to use $d$ instead of $\partial$ in total derivatives and under which conditions should I actually use $d$?